# Clearing the input file field after reselecting

Tags: jquery

I want to clear data from the input file multiple field every time I drop or select files, because when I choose files again, the old files are still there.

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple />
```

Comment: `$(selector).val('');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class (something like "toEmpty") to your inputs and clear them on specific acction (button click or whatever) with `$("toEmpty").val("");`